# Python Mayavi drawings are appearing black

Tags: python, mayavi

I am trying to run an example visualization from,
http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/building_applications.html

but the plot appears black as in,

[image]

while installing mayavi and its dependencies, I also received an error, 'vtkplywriter color is not updateable'.

What could be the reason for the lack of colors?

Comment: That error message suggests something is wrong with your underlying vtk installation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a mayavi installed with pythonxy (under windows) on a virtualbox (I don't know if it is linked to that.)

If I add the following line :

```
    self.plot.actor.mapper.interpolate_scalars_before_mapping = True
```

after this one:

```
    self.plot = self.scene.mlab.plot3d(x, y, z, t, colormap='Spectral')
```

it works better BUT it should work with interpolate_scalars_before_mapping = False.

**EDIT:**

My problem was due to the settings of my virtualbox. 
I checked "Enable 3D acceleration" and it works !

Comment: Thanks Yohann. I have been battling with the problem for some time. Your solution helped. In general, should I be initializing, 'interpolate_scalars_before_mapping = True', after the scene is called, in every program? (It worked by initializing after 'mlab.points3D' function in another mayavi example, http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_multiple_mlab_scene_models.html#example-multiple-mlab-scene-models

Comment: I have edited my answer. Are you working with a virtual environment ?